# Real time notification with socket.io, react.js and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I'm developing a gaming application with `react.js`, `node.js`, `express.js` and `sequelize`.

The application is simple, one player challenge another player (Active players) and play a game after challenge is accepted.

I'm trying to create a notification system with `socket.io`, but the `socket.emit()` isn't working under the `socket.on()` at `node.js`. I don't know what's going on?

Here my code:

> React

Sending this challenge request on challenge button click:

```
socket.emit('challenge request', { 
    player1_Name : localStorage.getItem('user-name'),
    player2 : response.data.data.player2_id,
    game : response.data.data.gameId,
    gameOption : response.data.data.gameOptionId,
    challengeStatus : response.data.data.challengeStatus
});
```

and trying to receive this notification from the `node.js`:

```
  socket.on("challenge-notify", function(data) {
    console.log("challenge Notify", data);
    helper(data.player1_Name,data.player2,data.game,data.gameOption);
  });
```

> Node

Here `socket.emit('challenge-notify')` function is not working under the `socket.on('challenge request')` method:

```
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('challenge request', function (challengeReq) {
          socket.emit('challenge-notify', { 
            player1_Name : challengeReq.player1_Name,
            player2 : challengeReq.player2,
            game : challengeReq.game,
            gameOption : challengeReq.gameOption,
            challengeStatus : challengeReq.challengeStatus
        });
    });
});
```

If I put `socket.emit('challenge-notify')` method outside my `socket.on('challenge request')` method then I'm getting the result at console when my react component load.

But I want this result whenever challenge button clicked. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you attaching the event listener for `challenge-notify` in your React app?

Comment: please add the onClickListener Code. It looks fine but i think your button click function may not be called. Have you tried out doing a console log when the button is pressed

Comment: Yes! onClickListener code is called and it emit the data socket.emit('challenge request')  at node too but When I tried to send that data socket.emit('challenge-notify')  from its not working. I also tried to console log when button is clicked I got the data at my node console. Means in the above code if i console.log(challengeReq) I will get each data at node console.

Comment: Hey Tholle, I put `challenge-notify` at the constructor() of my app.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Finally I found the solution..

I want to use `socket.emit` inside the `socket.on` to do this I used `io.sockets.emit` method and it works fine.

```
socket.on('challenge request', function (challengeReq) {
        io.sockets.emit('challenge-notify', { 
            player1_Name : challengeReq.player1_Name,
            player1: challengeReq.player1,
            player2 : challengeReq.player2,
            game : challengeReq.game,
            gameOption : challengeReq.gameOption,
            challengeStatus : challengeReq.challengeStatus

        });
    });
```